# Monitoring tool to microservices on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, microservices

I'm deploying an instance with kubernetes on Azure public cloud, and I need a tool to monitor the microservices and pods inside this instance, the question is, what tool are you using to do that?
I've been searching in a couple of places but without success.

Answer (score 1):

AKS

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-monitor.md

Looks interesting. I have not tried it myself, but based on the more than 300 github stars this looks interesting to me. The readme contains screen shots how to configure it in Azure.

Comment: Aren't those github stars for the azure-docs repo overall and not this specific tool?

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic dashboard which give some informations on your cluster. You can monitor basics metrics and this is the entry-level for Kubernetes monitoring.

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard

If you want something more complete, you could use the stack:
Prometheus with CAdvisor/node-exporter and Grafana

Answer (score 0):

monitoring resources (pods, node, storages) is importance. There are time we have issue with kubernetes pod which is in Crash result in service interupption.

IMHO, there are two thing need to take priority: Metrics and Logging.
We can use:
**Elastic Stack (ELK):** Discover how Elasticsearch, Kibana, Beats, and Logstash lay the foundation for various use cases, starting with logging and stretching the boundaries of imagination.

**Prometheus:** Uncover the distinguishing features of Prometheus, including its multidimensional data model, versatile query language (PromQL), and real-time alerting capabilities.

**Grafana:** Explore the dynamic world of Grafana, a versatile platform that excels in data visualization, monitoring, and crafting insightful dashboards.

**Kube-state-metrics:** Understand how this tool simplifies the utilization of Kubernetes API metrics to monitor resource health and performance.

**Datadog:** Delve into Datadog's robust integration of traces, metrics, and logs, revolutionizing application and infrastructure observability.

**Sumo Logic:** Learn about Sumo Logic's cutting-edge machine data analytics tailored for cloud-native environments.
I have documented an article about [7 Top Kubernetes Monitoring Tools](https://www.techvuehub.com/blog/7-top-kubernetes-monitoring-tools) hope can help